# How to process information from multiple lines in python?

Tags: python, parsing, readfile

I have a tab-delimited file that looks something like this:

```
\>WB02      \t F27C8.1  
IV  \t      B-9641      
\>WB03  \t  F07C3.7   
\>WB04  \t  F52H2.2   
\>WB04  \t  F52H2.2   
\>WB05  \t  T13A10.10     
IV  \t  B-15643   
IV  \t  B-11650   
IV  \t  B-13649
```

Using python, I would like to pair information from the lines that start with a '>' to information from any lines that follow that so not start with a '>.' Every time there is a '>' line followed by a non '>'line, I would like to print the column 2 value from the '>' line, followed by a tab, followed by the column 2 value from the non '>' line. For example:

```
F27C8.1 \t B-9641  
T13A10.10 \t B-15643  
T13A10.10 \t B-11650  
T13A10.10 \t B-13649
```

To now, I have written scrips that read files line-by-line. In this case, will I need to read the whole file into memory? The input file won't exceed about 30K lines, at about 10MB total. After that, I assume I will start with something like "For each line that does not start with a '>' get the value from column 2 of the nearest preceeding line that starts with a '>.' I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction for reading - this is a bit more complicated than anything I have done so far (baby steps!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this by reading the file incrementally. You just need to keep a variable to save the value of the last > line you've seen. So, something like this:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    lastmarkedline = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            lastmarkedline = line
        elif lastmarkedline is not None:
            field1 = lastmarkedline.split()[1]
            field2 = line.split()[1]
            print "{0}\t{1}".format(field1, field2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully - and is so much simpler than what I was envisioning!

Answer (score 1):

You can process the file line by line, checking each line to see if it begins with a ">". When you encounter a line that starts with ">", capture the value in column two. For lines that don't begin with ">", you can output the last captured value along with the associated sub-value.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lastHeader = ''
    for line in f:
        pieces = line.split('\t')
        if line[0] == '>':
            lastHeader = pieces[1].strip()
        else:
            print "%s  \t  %s" % (lastHeader, pieces[1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to keep track of the last line that starts with `'>'`. You could tweak the script depending on how robust it should be against an invalid input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

last = None
for line in fileinput.input():
    mark, sep, value = line.partition('\t')
    if not sep: continue # skip lines without a tab
    if mark.startswith('>WB'):
       last = value.strip()
    elif mark.strip() == 'IV':
       print('%s\t%s' % (last, value.strip()))
```

#### Usage

```
$ python thescript.py input.txt
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/BOnXg)

```
F27C8.1 B-9641
T13A10.10   B-15643
T13A10.10   B-11650
T13A10.10   B-13649
```